# React onChange works only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to recreate the functionality of ToggleButtonGroup and ToggleButton from react-bootstrap.

Here's my component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import ButtonRadio from "PointAndClick/components/ButtonRadio";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState } from '../../features/store';
import '../css/GameAnswers.css';
import GameImage from '../components/GameImage';

type GameAnswersProps = {
    setFinishedGame: Function
}

function GameAnswers(props: GameAnswersProps) {
    const gameAnswers = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.GameDataReducer.gameAnswers);    
    const gameImages = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.GameDataReducer.gameImages);
    const correctAnswer = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.GameDataReducer.correctAnswers);
    const gameQuestion = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.GameDataReducer.gameQuestion);
    
    const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState("");
    let iconAnswer = "";

    const handleAnswerChange = function (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        console.log(e.target);
        setSelectedAnswer(e.target.value);
    }

    const determineButtonVariant = function (answer: string) {
        if (answer !== selectedAnswer) {
            return "primary";
        } else if (answer === correctAnswer) {
            props.setFinishedGame(true);
            iconAnswer="check";
            return "success";
        } else {
            props.setFinishedGame(false);
            iconAnswer="times";
            return "danger";
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="game-answers">
            {
            gameImages === undefined &&
                    <GameImage 
                    className="game-details-image" 
                    images={[{ imgSrc: gameQuestion, imgAlt: 'test' }]} />
            }
            <div className="btn-group btn-group-custom">
                {gameAnswers.map(function (answer, index) {
                    return <ButtonRadio
                            id={answer}
                            value={answer}
                            onChange={handleAnswerChange}
                            className={`btn btn-${determineButtonVariant(answer)}${gameImages !== undefined ? "btn-img" : ""}`}
                        >
                        {gameImages !== undefined && 
                        <GameImage 
                        className="game-answers-image"
                        images={[{ imgSrc: gameImages[index], imgAlt: 'test' }]} />
                    }
                            {iconAnswer !== "" && determineButtonVariant(answer) !== "primary" ? 
                            <i className={`fa fa-${iconAnswer} fa-${iconAnswer}-custom`}/> :
                            ""
                            }
                            {answer}
                        </ButtonRadio>
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default GameAnswers;
```

ButtonRadio.tsx

```
import "../css/Button.css";

type ButtonRadioProps = {
    className: string,
    children: React.ReactNode,
    name: string,
    id?: string,
    value?: string,
    onChange?: any
}

function ButtonRadio(props: ButtonRadioProps)
{
    return (
        <>
        <input
        type="radio" 
        id={props.id}
        value={props.value}
        className="btn-check"
        onChange={props.onChange}
        autoComplete="off"
        />
        <label 
        className={props.className}
        htmlFor={props.id}
        role="button"
        tabIndex={0}
        >
        {props.children}
        </label>
        </>
    );
}

export default ButtonRadio;
```

When I was using react-bootstrap, the only difference was the return function which looked like this:

```
return (
        <div className="game-answers">
            {
                gameImages === undefined &&
                    <GameImage 
                    className="game-details-image" 
                    images={[{ imgSrc: gameQuestion, imgAlt: 'test' }]} />
            }
            <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="answers" className="btn-group-custom">
                {gameAnswers.map(function (answer, index) {
                    return <ToggleButton
                            id={answer}
                            value={answer}
                            onChange={handleAnswerChange}
                            variant={determineButtonVariant(answer)}
                            bsPrefix={gameImages !== undefined ? "btn-img" : ""}
                        >
                        {gameImages !== undefined && 
                        <GameImage 
                        className="game-answers-image"
                        images={[{ imgSrc: gameImages[index], imgAlt: 'test' }]} />
                    }
                            {iconAnswer !== "" && determineButtonVariant(answer) !== "primary" ? 
                            <i className={`fa fa-${iconAnswer} fa-${iconAnswer}-custom`}/> :
                            ""
                            }
                            {answer}
                        </ToggleButton>
                })}
            </ToggleButtonGroup>
        </div>
    );
```

and everything worked fine.

Now I tried to do it myself (the first piece of code in the post) and it works but only partially.

The onChange event is only called once on each button.

Example:

```
I click on answer1: onChange called
I click on answer2: onChange called
I click on answer1 again: onChange isn't called anymore (I expected it to be called again)
```

Why can this be happening and how can I fix it? I found already something on Google, but not useful to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i think your main issue is due to you using onChange instead of onClick.

Had a bit of a rework here if this is any use to show you what i changed
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-queeta?file=Hello.tsx

Comment: It's working. But can you explain why? :) Also, the link doesn't work me.

Comment: Sorry not sure why the links not working maybe try in chrome?

Comment: The reason onChange wont work a second time is the value is already set so clicking it again shouldn't change anything but onClick wont care about the state so calling it again will register anyway. 
MDN HTMLElement: change event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: It doesn't load on Firefox. (not on my PC and not on my phone). Thanks for your answer though :)